# Dart in Existing Eclipse Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, dart, project

When I add simple dart files anywhere in my existing Eclipse project, what do I have to do and what will be the limitiations and work arounds in order to make it work.

Update:

Some additional information might be helpful. What I use is a custom web server serving dart and js as simple files (dynamically on request). So I can not simply follow the dart way of things. The dart files would be rather sources only being used during development and converted to js files before the actual check in of the new version.

Therefore I would like to add the dart files in exactly the same mannor I add my other source. So i would love to have something like src/main/dart and src/test/dart or something.

I would also like being able to run dart in the stand alone vm (stand alone application) instead of the web / browser to simplify some development steps like the development of the model / business layer and add simplified testing. Also we want to evaluate if there is the possibility to start dart side processes on the server for additional simplification.

So the scenario is:

1. Put dart files anywhere (especially in the source tree)
2. The web framework is non-standard programmer friendly, we can simply add resources from anywhere under virtual directories (src/main/dart -> localhost/dart/)
3. The dart files will be converted to js prior to checkin
4. Dart should be able to pickup the right files on debug
5. Testing and debugging should be possible in standalone mode and in using Dartium

So how can I do this what should I be able to configure.

Update2:

Dart will be used as a JavaScript replacement here. So in the end this is a mid-size web project where the JS/Dart code provides the glue to make the pages functional. It also will drive the backend application which might be single paged but its not decided yet. Best would be to see the dart application as of two applications at once where the backedn application is distinct from the front end functionality that is dynamically added as needed.

For the compilation process to JS I would not mind to create a simple program copying files, compile and recopy files and done. Wouldnt take that long since it would be only needed once or twice a day.

Comment: I assume this is for Dart in a single page application for the browser (Dart also can run on the server).
Of course you can put Dart files everywhere you want but where it makes sense depends on what you want Dart to do for you ;-). Your question contains no information about that.

Comment: You still didn't say what you want Dart do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Dart `pub` package.
That is a directory containing the file `pubspec.yaml`.
You can put the Dart script and HTML files in the `web` and or `lib` subdirectory of the Dart package.
When you run `pub build` the deployable output is generated in the `build/web` subdirectory.
This deployable files can be served by your web server like any other static web content like HTML, CSS, JavaScript files.

### update

1. I can't think of a way doing this
   Dart isn't like JavaScript where you add some event handler script here and there. 
   I can't see how this would make sense anyway. More information about what you want Dart do for you is necessary to answer this - see my comment above.
2. You need the build step prior to serve generated JavaScript.
   A Dart app is built entirely at once not file by file.
3. this is what `pub build` does. The output is written to `my_dart_package/build/web`
4. You can debug Dart as Dart (in Dartium, DartEditor or any other IDE that supports debugging Dart code) or after the build step using source maps in a browser like Chrome, FireFox, ...
5. You can debug non-web code standalone using the debugger of DartEditor, WebStorm, ...
   You can create unit tests that invoke methods on Dart classes (model classes, PODO, ...) without a browser.
   When you want to debug code that depends on the `dart:html` package you can only do it using a browser.

### update2

You could create three packages
- server
- client
- shared

Dynamically loading functionality is already supported. The functionality has to be available at build time but can be loaded 'deferred' at first access or on request but this has nothing to do with the server part of Dart this is client-only functionality. Any web server can be used for that (for example Apache).

The server usually provided some data APIs (HTTP, REST, WebSocket, ...) for the client.

Comment: I want to avoid any of those requirements. I want to use dart just the way I would use js. Put it anywhere in the project, let the server serve the right file and done. I have updated the original question to provide further information.

Comment: As far as I understood, dart is using the src files inside the browser. Wasnt that one advantage over java, that the byte code generation can be done on the fly inside the VM?

Comment: There is currently no browser that supports Dart directly beside Dartium which is development only and not meant for production use so the question is a bit theoretical. When you transpile Dart to JavaScript nothing the like applies anymore. Dart2JS adds a lot of boilerplate code to support Dart features like classes and a lot more therefore Dart2JS does tree-shaking to eliminate unused code. This can only be done when the entire code base is available therefore a Dart app can only be build all at once. Dart is not a replacement for inline JavaScript. Dart is for building SPAs.

Comment: Because you still haven't provided any information about what you want to do with Dart my comment is only about assumptions I made.

Comment: I updated the question. I just want to recreate JS before checkin and it will be a JS replacement like GWT we used before. Dart will only be used during development time. There might be dart application somehow but its vague up to now.

Comment: Ok, that already tells a lot more but what why do you want to use it only during development time? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Compiling to JavaScript takes a lot of time so the dart version (not the compiled JavaScript version) is used for instant start and debug. Maybe you misstook the during development. Production -> JS only. Development -> Dart. Dart -> JS.

Comment: This is the normal development workflow. Develop only with Dart and when it works build to JavaScript and test and occassionally debug in JavaScript-only browsers (when something works in Dart but not in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, ...).

So is your question - how to migrate a GWT application to a Dart application in small steps?

Comment: Nope its a reimplementation. There is no GWT left. Its a new version started from scratch but reusing the implementation details as a blue print. Its like porting the existing tests and then make it work by reimplementing / porting the required code. But features change and some other details and requirements also a lot of libs change too.

Comment: I guess I understand your situation now (beside the details of the custom web server you use) but I don't know what further information I could provide that could be useful to you. Dart requires a directory containing the `pubspec.yaml` and a subdirectory `lib` within `lib` there are no further conventions. The `web` directory only contains the entry page (`index.html`) which can be built in a way so it doesn't contain anything but a few imports (CSS, Scripts, ...). You can also put all your code below `web` but this can cause troubles with some frameworks like Angular.dart which expect `lib`.

Comment: Thats what I understood. For the browser it is just a file it gets by request. And as far as I understood the Debugging session within Dartium is just a Remote Debugging connection. The actual debugging is done only on the browser side.

Comment: The Dart VM provides a debugging interface. When you debug a web page DartEditors debugger connects to Dartiums Dart VM, when you debug a console/server app DartEditors debugger connects to the standalone VM.
Debugging Dart is similar to debugging a Java application in Eclipse.
A web page can also be debugged in Dartium directly (using the Chrome developer console) like with JavaScript.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thanks for clarification. So all I need to do is get chromium to start with my web server/s page and get a debugging session to find the sources. I will give it a try.